# Specify individual target build settings with xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, fastlane

I have an iOS app that uses Cocoapods, and has a local cocoa touch framework target, and I'm running into an issue with specifying build settings in the command line using `xcodebuild`.

I understand that you can specify build settings like `PROVISIONING_PROFILE`, `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY`, and `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` by appending their `key=value` pair to the end of the command.

However those setting appear to be applied to the entire project, but I only need them to apply to the app target since touch frameworks cannot be signed.

How do I specify build settings for an individual target using xcodebuild? If it cannot be done using xcodebuild, could this be accomplished using fastlane?

Comment: Use a scheme... that way you can isolate your targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use schemes. You can set the scheme to build/archive with a particular build configuration and executable.